# convert Obj-C to Swift ep1

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

i want your help to convert Obj-C to Swift, because i have no idea about Obj-C

viewController.h :

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#define kPostURL @"http://localhost/tutorialTest.php"
#define kName @"name"
#define kMessage @"message"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController{

IBOutlet UITextField *nameText;
IBOutlet UITextView *messageText;
NSURLConnection *postConnection;

}

-(IBAction)save:(id)sender;

@end
```

viewController.m :

```
 -(void) postMessage:(NSString*) message withName:(NSString *) name{

    if (name != nil && message !=nil){

        NSMutableString *postString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:kPostURL];

        [postString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"?%@=%@", kName, name]];

        [postString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"&%@=%@", kMessage, message]];

        [postString setString:[postString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:postString]];
       [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

        postConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];

    }
}
```

i hope you guys can help me to translate to Swift. thx

Comment: SO is not a code-writing service. Please review the [guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question (that won't be downvoted immediately).

Comment: http://objectivec2swift.net

Comment: yeah sorry, little bit confuse to ask what a point the question about convert obj-C to Swift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this might help a bit.
Its not exact translation but you can modify by solving compile time and run time errors.

```
func postMessage(message: String, withName name: String) {
    if name != nil && message != nil {
        var postString: NSMutableString = NSMutableString.stringWithString(kPostURL)
        postString.appendString("?\(kName)=\(name)")
        postString.appendString("&\(kMessage)=\(message)")
        postString.setString(postString.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding))
        var request: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(uRL: NSURL.URLWithString(postString))
        request.setHTTPMethod("POST")
        postConnection = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self, startImmediately: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: tq for your solution, i will check that

Comment: works, with bit modify, in swift NSURL.URLWithString is not available anymore, just NSURL(String : String). request.setHTTPMethod is not available but exchange request.HTTPMethod = "POST"